# Get image to display inline with unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am really struggling to get a image to display inline with unordered list.

HTML:

```
<div class="customer-indiv man">
  <a class="customer_thumb" href="/fan/332profile.com">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WiAvs8Q.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/fan/332profile.com">name of user</a></li>
    <li>phone no</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.customer_thumb {
  display: inline-block;
}
.customer-indiv {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: .8em 0;
}
.customer-indiv:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.customer-indiv:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

I'd like it to be displayed, with the image to the left and the 3 li's to the right, which I believe is what my CSS should do. Like so:

```
        name
IMAGE   phone no
        text
```

Unfortunately, at the moment it outputs:

```
IMAGE
name
phone no
text
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve that:

1. Flexbox

```css
.customer-indiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.customer_thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-indiv man">
  <a class="customer_thumb" href="/fan/332profile.com">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WiAvs8Q.jpg" />
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/fan/332profile.com">name of user</a></li>
    <li>phone no</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. CSS table

```css
.customer-indiv {
  display: table;
}
.customer-indiv > a,
.customer-indiv > ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.customer_thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-indiv man">
  <a class="customer_thumb" href="/fan/332profile.com">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WiAvs8Q.jpg" />
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/fan/332profile.com">name of user</a></li>
    <li>phone no</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

3. Inline blocks

```css
.customer-indiv {
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
}
.customer-indiv > a,
.customer-indiv > ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.customer_thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-indiv man">
  <a class="customer_thumb" href="/fan/332profile.com">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WiAvs8Q.jpg" />
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/fan/332profile.com">name of user</a></li>
    <li>phone no</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5tLdgy6/1/)

CSS :

```
.customer_thumb img { max-width: 50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
ul {  display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; }
```